# Objective C: как клонировать UIView?

Tags: objective-c

Доброго времени суток. 
Суть вопроса. Есть два `View`, в одном находится таблица и кнопка. Нужно клонировать `View` с таблицей на другой несколько раз. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?
Спасибо.  
PS. После `gogle` понял, что надо писать функцию типа

```
-(UIView *)cloneView:(UIView *)myView {  
   ................  
   return cloneView;  
}
```

А вот что писать вместо точек остается тайной.

Comment: @Pavlyuk, я советую вам для точности переименовать ваш вопрос: замените "копировать" на "клонировать".

Comment: Я никогда не сталкивался с подобной задачей. Предварительное знание о вопросе и беглый осмотр SO показывают, что прямого решения не существует, поэтому прежде чем, я начну предлагать косвенные, опишите, для чего вам это нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот возможные косвенные решения вопроса:

1) [UIView duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131351/uiview-duplicate) предлагает архивировать UIView:

```
-(UIView *)cloneView:(UIView *)aView {
    NSData *archivedViewData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    id clone = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedViewData];
    return clone;
}
```

Этот метод должен работать с ограничением на views, которые не могут быть архивированы:

```
Unfortunately, this won't work if your view has any subviews/objects that can't be archived (such as a UIImage)
```

что означает, что если у вас есть картинки, то это решение не сработает.

2) Другое решение [You can load a view from a XIB file several times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820050/598057) предлагает создать xib-файл с вашим view, чтобы он с помощью

```
[NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:@"ReusedView" owner:self options:nil];
```

порождал экземляры этого view.

3) Третье [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10367029/598057) предлагает не клонирование, а просто перерисовку оригинального view.

4) Моё предложение:

Вы так и не ответили, для чего именно вам понадобилось клонирование - это решение сгодится для не совсем-сложных-и-частных случаев -

Вы создаёте для своих view специальные подклассы UIView, в которые добавляете метод:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    UIView *copyView = [UIView allocWithZone:zone] initWithFrame:self.frame];

    // Здесь процедура порождения копии

    return copyView;
}
```

И в теле этого метода скопировать всё содержимое вашего view шаг за шагом.

Этот способ мне кажется самым надёжным и удобным. И если вам действительно нужны Клоны, то можно в `copyWithZone` описать всю вашу, даже возможно сложную, процедуру порождения копии.

Да, и кстати, "решение" @Bimawa начнёт работать именно в том виде, в котором он описал.

На SO я встречал соображение, что когда-нибудь Apple реализует `-[UIView copyWithZone]`, поэтому ещё раз повторю, что это копирование лучше делать в методе `copyWithZone` *подкласса* UIView, а не, скажем, категории типа UIView+Cloning, чтобы не "засорять" UIView и его производные классы.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Интересно узнать, подошло ли вам какое-нибудь решение - напишите сюда потом в комменты, пожалуйста ;)

Comment: Так как пока только начинаю программировать реализовать это не пытался. Просто создал XIB с нужным View и копировал его. За ответ спасибо. В дальнейшем попробую реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *view = [UIView new];
UIView *view2=[view copy];
```

Comment: Так не получается вылетает вот так:
-[UIView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7557560'

Answer (score 0):

Мне тоже понадобился этот "а зачем вам это нужно". Я нашел очень простой и удобный способ делать клоны с использованием шаблонов storyboard.  Для этого я создаю в своем объекте myController класса UIViewController нужный объект, например UIView, и кладу его в нижнюю строку конструктора (совершенно не обязательно). Далее создаю на него именованный outlet, например footerShooter.

Когда мне нужна копия объекта, я создаю myController *controller, используя storyboard по  идентификатору. Далее извлекаю нужный объект по ссылке controller.footerShooter, а от controller избавляюсь. Вот и все.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *view = [UIView new];
UIView *copyView = [viewsnapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```