# Копирование NSManagedObject-подкласса

Tags: objective-c, coredata

Существует некий `NSManagedObject`-подкласс `Visit`. Появилась необходимость получить почти точную копию обьекта - из двадцати полей нужно изменить значение у трех. Можно ли сделать копию не таким трудоемким процессом как

```
....
for(Visit *copiedVisit in arrayOfVisits) // массив обьектов с которых делаются копии
{
    Visit *newVisit = (Visit *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Visit" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
newVisit.date = [NSDate someNewDate];  // поле которое нужно изменить
newVisit.name = copiedVisit.name;         // далее переприсвоение значений полей одного объекта = полям     другого
newVisit.attribute = copiedVisit.attribute;
newVisit.time = copiedVisit.time;
...

NSError *err = nil;
if (![self managedObjectContext] save:&err])
 {
    ...
 };
}
```

а потом переприсвоением значений полей одного объекта полям другого? Некий аналог `copy` для `NSManagedObject`-подкласса?

Comment: Можно пример того, как происходит это копирование, добавить в вопрос? Я имею в виду в "трудоемком" варианте.

Comment: конечно, сейчас допишу в апдейт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, у Core Data нет такой возможности из коробки. Мне кажется, вполне уместно определить для вашего класса Visit соответствующий метод -copyWithZone: в котором можно описать всю процедуру порождения копии, и затем пользоваться просто обычным copy, как вы и предполагаете в своем вопросе - только не "аналогом copy", а самым настоящим copy, потому что именно так он и работает - через определение copyWithZone.

Смотри мой ответ про клонирование UIView: 
[Objective C: как клонировать UIView?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207211/objective-c-objective-c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-uiview)
.

Comment: на полученный при помощи метода copy потом вызвать стандартное сохранение? Будут ли таким образом сохранены связи, или только значения полей?

Comment: Это зависит исключительно от того, как написана процедура. Вот пример того, как можно сделать автоперечисление свойств и отношений(relationships).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730832/how-can-i-duplicate-or-copy-a-core-data-managed-object